# android development for smartphone and/or tablet

Tags: android

I recently registered myself as android developer and I am now starting to use sdk. I am an Android newbie but have experience on iOS development and when building an app using xcode, you can develop it for iPhone (compatibility mode for iPad) or exclusively for iPad in order to enhache resolution and functionalities for this device. What about android? Is only one development for both devices, smartphone and tablet? Thank you to solve me this basic concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and I recommend you that if you are starting to develop in Android, read this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

With fragments you can control if is tablet or mobile. Also you can download the Google IO application and see what they do. The source code is available here: http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Hope this helps...

Comment: your first link is broken

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare in the AndroidManifest.xml file the screen sizes supported by your application.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

This page also describe how you can develop your application for different screen sizes:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html